# React Native - inconsistent display for borderStyle: 'dashed'

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-stylesheet

Trying to use

```
StyleSheet.create({
 row: {
   borderStyle: 'dashed', 
   borderWidth: 1,
 },
})
```

or any `borderWidth` and getting inconsistency with dark outlines on some of my elements.

Is this a known bug?

[image: Border Display on iOS]

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it's an issue but I solved this by wrapping my dashed border view with another `<View>` that sets a background color.

[image]